# Confusion about the proof of Menger's Theorem in "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas West

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, connectedness, graph-connectivity

The proof of Menger's Theorem in the book "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas West (2nd Edition; Page 167) has been divided into two cases.

The second case assumes that

> "Every minimum $x,y$-cut is $N(x)$ or $N(y)$",

where $N(x)$ denote the set of neighbors of $x$.

However, it seems that the graph for Case 2 (see below) in the illustration does not satisfy this assumption. What is going on here?

[image: Case2]

Comment: Do you have the link to the book? I can only find solution manual: http://home.ku.edu.tr/mudogan/public_html/Introduction%20to%20Graph%20Theory%202E%20-%20West.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illustrations will match up with the cases, if we change the descriptions of the cases to:

**Case 1'.** $G$ has a minimum $x,y$-cut $S$ not contained in $N(x) \cup N(y)$.

**Case 2'.** Every minimum $x,y$-cut is contained in $N(x) \cup N(y)$.

If we follow these descriptions, then the proof still works, because the only way we use the assumption in case 2 is to say that every vertex outside $\{x\} \cup N(x) \cup N(y) \cup \{y\}$ is in no minimum $x,y$-cut, and this is still true in case 2'. (Since case 1' is a subcase of case 1, there is nothing to worry about there.)

In general, whenever $G$ falls under both case 1 and case 2' (that is, every minimum $x,y$-cut is contained in $N(x) \cup N(y)$, but there is some minimum $x,y$-cut $S$ not equal to $N(x)$ or $N(y)$) then we can handle $G$ by the argument from either case, which is where this flexibility comes from.

---

Pedagogical note: when I taught this proof last year, I began by considering the case where $N(x) \cap N(y) = \varnothing$ and $V(G) = \{x\} \cup N(x) \cup N(y) \cup \{y\}$, which falls under case 2' and is the case where we can apply König-Egerváry. Then I dealt with the three possibilities below:

1. $v \in N(x) \cap N(y)$, which is handled in the case 2 proof. (Delete $v$, reducing $\kappa(x,y)$ by $1$.)
2. $v \notin \{x\} \cup N(x) \cup N(y) \cup \{y\}$, but $v$ is not part of any minimum $x,y$-cut, which is also handled in the case 2 proof. (Delete $v$, not changing $\kappa(x,y)$.)
3. There is a minimum $x,y$-cut $S$ not contained in $N(x) \cup N(y)$. (This is case 1', and we can apply the case 1 proof.)

In some sense, this is the logical progression: we apply König-Egerváry for some cases, and then show that all other cases can be reduced to smaller ones.